# What does DAPM routing in ALSA ASoC simple-audio-card driver mean?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-device-driver, alsa

The kernel doc `doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sound/simple-card.txt` gives an example of how to use it in device tree:

```
sound {
    compatible = "simple-audio-card";
    ...
    simple-audio-card,widgets =
        "Microphone", "Microphone Jack",
        "Headphone", "Headphone Jack",
        "Speaker", "External Speaker";
    simple-audio-card,routing =
        "MIC_IN", "Microphone Jack",
        "Headphone Jack", "HP_OUT",
        "External Speaker", "LINE_OUT";
    ...
```

The "Microphone", "Headphone" and "Speaker" are just identifiers (allowed ones are only "Microphone", "Headphone", "Speaker", "Line"). Names "MIC_IN", "HP_OUT" and "LINE_OUT" are the real things of the hardware codec that its driver reports.

What are the made up names like "Microphone Jack", "Headphone Jack" and "External Speaker"? Where do they come up and how are they important (they don't map 1 to 1 to the userspace ALSA devices, those names never appear in the userspace)? How do they affect hardware codecs?

Answer (score 2):

In short, the name used in "simple-audio-card,routing" is actually the name you have defined and renamed in "simple-audio-card, widgets".

Another important notes is that "simple-audio-card, widgets" could possibly define e.g. two speakers widget:

```
"Speaker", "External Speaker";
"Speaker", "Internal Speaker";
```

The first "Speaker" is the template name, The second is the instance name.

TL;DR:

I came across this questions recently as well. After having done some code reading, following is my understanding:

Following DTS definitions do two things:

```
simple-audio-card,widgets =
        "Microphone", "Microphone Jack",
        "Headphone", "Headphone Jack",
        "Speaker", "External Speaker";
```

1. It defines/creates machine level (sound card level) widgets, like "Speaker", "Microphone", "Headphone".
2. The DTS also allows the rename it to custom defined name. So "Microphone" is renamed to "Microphone Jack", etc.

This could be read from the code as shown below. So the future widget name referenced from "simple-audio-card,routing" should be the ones after renaming.

In the file kernel/sound/soc/soc-core.c:

```
static const struct snd_soc_dapm_widget simple_widgets[] = {
    SND_SOC_DAPM_MIC("Microphone", NULL),
    SND_SOC_DAPM_LINE("Line", NULL),
    SND_SOC_DAPM_HP("Headphone", NULL),
    SND_SOC_DAPM_SPK("Speaker", NULL),
};
```

Above defines a widget template.

```
int snd_soc_of_parse_audio_simple_widgets(struct snd_soc_card *card,
                    const char *propname)
```

In above function, it will try to match the name shown in the DTs to the template by the name and then change the name to the one in the second column (in DTS)

The document widget.txt actually repeats the same:

kernel/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sound/widgets.txt

> Widgets:
>
> This mainly specifies audio off-codec DAPM widgets.
>
> Each entry is a pair of strings in DT:
>
> ```
> "template-wname", "user-supplied-wname"
> ```
>
> The "template-wname" being the template widget name and currently
> includes: "Microphone", "Line", "Headphone" and "Speaker".
>
> The "user-supplied-wname" being the user specified widget name.
>
> For instance:
> simple-audio-widgets =
> "Microphone", "Microphone Jack",
> "Line", "Line In Jack",
> "Line", "Line Out Jack",
> "Headphone", "Headphone Jack",
> "Speaker", "Speaker External";

I am not an ALSA expert, and unfortunately I could not understand the document until I have read the code.